Playwright report not showing error screenshot
I have a Playwright project set up that runs a test with an ADO pipeline and captures a screenshot and trace on failure.
The problem I'm having is that the screenshot doesn't display in the html report, it has to be downloaded to be able to be viewed. Please can anyone help me to resolve this:
Generated Report

If I click on the screenshot or trace link, I get this error:

Published Artifacts

playwright.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  fullyParallel: false,
  reporter: [['html', { open: 'never' }]],
  use: {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
  },

ado_pipeline.yaml
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: tests/playwright-report
      artifact: playwright-report
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()

